# How do I resolve this error on typing the "ant" command in Git shell

Tags: git, shell, ant, repository

I am trying to build a repository on my Windows PC from Git using the Git shell.
The name of the repository is "**newrep**".

While doing so when I type the command "**ant**", it throws the following error -

`The term ant is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a patch was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line: 1 char :4
+ ant <<<< + CategoryInfo           :ObjectNotFound: (ant:String) [],                                                         CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId  : CommandNotFoundException`

How do I resolve this bug?

Comment: Have you installed Ant?

Comment: yes, it is installed in the C drive and my github repositories are in the F drive.

Comment: Is the directory with the Ant binary listed in the PATH environment variable?

Comment: yes, that was missing.thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have a bat file which sets the `ANT_HOME` and prints the `ant -version` output.

After executing this `bat` file from `powershell` if I type `"ant -version"` I get the same error as above.

However the `"ant all"` command executes without any issues if I add it in the same bat file,and execute the bat file again.

So what I understand from this is, unlike `command prompt`, `powershell` doesn't set local session properties.